# AWS ECS agent won't start

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

When I try to run the ECS agent, I get the following error in the ecs-init.log*:

```
[INFO] Agent exited with code 5
[ERROR] agent exited with terminal exit code
```

And in the ecs-agent.log* file I get this:

```
[CRITICAL] Data mismatch; saved cluster 'cluster1' does not match configured cluster 'cluster2'. Perhaps you want to delete the configured checkpoint file?
```

Any idea where is that checkpoint file?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I found the answer myself. The checkpoint file is located in this directory: `/var/lib/ecs/data/ecs_agent_data.json`.
Just delete that json file and start the ECS agent again running `start ecs`.
Thanks to this forum post, which indirectly led me to the answer: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=625643

Answer (score 26):

delete checkpoint file form below location

```
sudo rm /var/lib/ecs/data/agent.db
```

now start ecs agent

```
sudo systemctl start ecs

sudo systemctl status ecs
```